# opencv-python: How to draw an image contour

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I want to find the contours in my image as:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os, sys

OriginalImage = cv2.imread('test.png',0)   # get the a gray-scale image
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(221),plt.imshow(OriginalImage,'gray')

GaussianImage = cv2.GaussianBlur(OriginalImage,(3,3),0)
plt.subplot(222),plt.imshow(GaussianImage,'gray')

ret,thrsh_GaussianImage =       cv2.threshold(GaussianImage,50,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
plt.subplot(223),plt.imshow(thrsh_GaussianImage,'gray')
plt.show()

im, contours, hierarchy =     cv2.findContours(thrsh_GaussianImage,cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(thrsh_GaussianImage,contours,-1,(0,255,0),3)
cv2.imshow("j", im)
cv2.waitKey()
```

---

but the problem is that the last image which is my contour is not shown.
I also deleted the plt. shows... still it does not show anything. 
What should I do to get my contours displayed?

I checked the previous posts... they had suggested to add the last 2 lines but still it does not work for me.

one more thing is that in my pycharm page 
     import numpy as np
is not colored as blue and gray... It is all gray... However it works. But I do not know why it is like that!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
cv2.drawContours(thrsh_GaussianImage,contours,-1,(128,255,0),3)
```

If you figure out why, please post about it. I don't have time right now to play around with it or research it.